# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() in WorkManager

Tags: android, android-handler, android-workmanager

I am trying to implement a `WorkManager` for a periodic background operation.  I'm getting a common error when trying to use a `Handler` in the `Worker`.  I know the error is saying I need to call `Looper.prepare()` because I'm on the wrong thread but I'm not sure how to.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class SyncWorker extends Worker {

    private static TimeOutHandler mTimeOutHandler;

    public SyncWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
        mTimeOutHandler = new TimeOutHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {    
        return Result.success();
    }

    private static class TimeOutHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<SyncWorker> mMainWeakReference;

        //this is where the error is thrown
        TimeOutHandler(final SyncWorker service) {
            mMainWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(service);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            final SyncWorker service = mMainWeakReference.get();

            if (service != null) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MESSAGE_CONNECTIVITY_TIMEOUT:
                        mTimeOutHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_CONNECTIVITY_TIMEOUT);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

I've done some research and one suggested solution is to use:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

but I don't know how to do that with the way I'm extending `Handler`.

Comment: Inside your `TimeOutHandler` constructor, put this as very first line `super(Looper.getMainLooper());`.

Comment: damn, I knew it was something easy I was missing.  Thanks.  If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it so you get credit.  Thanks.

Comment: But the more points you get the more you can do a Bounty and get a tough question answered in case you get stuck on a problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You've created constructor **extending `Handler`** class, and you've added parameters for your **constructor** there are several ways to provide `Looper` to your `Handler` like below suggested approach.

1. You can create another constructor that access `Looper` also:

   ```
   TimeOutHandler(final SyncWorker service, Looper looper) {
       super(looper);
       mMainWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(service);
   }
   ```

   And initialize like :

   ```
   TimeOutHandler handler = new TimeOutHandler(service, Looper.getMainLooper());
   ```
2. Directly passing `Looper` to primary constructor:

   ```
   TimeOutHandler(final SyncWorker service) {
       super(Looper.getMainLooper());
       mMainWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(service);
   }
   ```

---

So calling **super()** initialize constructor of parent *(super)* class & in our case, we pass `Looper` as parameter to **super** will initialize Handler with constructor **`Handler(Looper looper)`** which previously was **`Handler()`** *(Empty or default constructor)*.

**Note:** The thing is [**Handler**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#public-constructors_1) class has multiple constructors from which one accepts `Looper` which is provided to switch `Handler` to specific thread provided.

Comment: did not work to me

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind your code isn't going to work as you expect, even when you successfully implement a Handler.  Your process is eligible to be stopped as soon as you return a Result from your Worker class.  What you really want is a [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker), and to complete your ListenableFuture when you are done with your asynchronous calculation.